# How to make a global function for UIAlertController(ActionSheet) to access in many classes of project

Tags: ios, swift3, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet

I want to make a function in `NSObject` class for `UIAlertCotroller`. So that I can access this function in any class. I have tried with that following code:

```
open class func showActionSheet(_ delegate: UIViewController, message: String, strtittle: String, handler: ((UIAlertController) -> Void)! = nil)
    {
        let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: strtittle, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

        if handler == nil{
            actionSheetController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Default(Off)" , style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
            }))
        }
        else{
            actionSheetController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Default(Off)" , style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

            }))
        }

        delegate.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: {
            print("completion block")
        })
    }
```

This is the function that I made, but problem is there can be number of actions in ActionSheet and they also have different tittle and different styles.

**Question:** How can I make this function? Please Help.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588882/swift-how-to-present-viewcontroller-when-tapping-button-in-a-custom-alertcontr/41589066#41589066

Comment: Thanks for that, I think this is for AlertController(Alert type) only. I am looking for AlertController(Action sheet).

Comment: You just need to change that, that's why i have write you can try like this way. Also you can add one string array parameter for action title.

Comment: Is that mean I have to know about maximum number of actions?

Comment: Something like this way `func buildAlertInfoWithFavButton(withTitle title: String?, andMessage message: String?, withActionTitles titles:[String], withHandler handler: [((UIAlertAction) -> Void)]?) -> UIAlertController {` Pass array of action titles also.

Comment: Hm, I understand. Let me try will know you about it soon. Thanks!

Comment: @NiravD Thanku for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution of my problem by using this [Swift - How to present ViewController when tapping button in a custom AlertController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588882/swift-how-to-present-viewcontroller-when-tapping-button-in-a-custom-alertcontr/41589066#41589066)

Their are following modification that I have to do to achieve my goal. Here is the code:

**In Controller Class:**

```
 Alert.showActionSheet(self, message: "Save incoming media for this chat",strtittle: "",actionTittle: ["Default(Off)","Always","Never","Cancel"],
                                        actionStyle:  [.default,.default,.default,.cancel] ,
                                        withHandler:  [defaultHandler, alwaysHandler, neverHandler, cancelHandler])

func defaultHandler(action: UIAlertAction) {
        //Add code of present
        print("DefaultHandler")
    }

    func alwaysHandler(action: UIAlertAction) {
        //Add code of present
        print("alwaysHandler")

    }

    func neverHandler(action: UIAlertAction) {
        //Add code of present
         print("neverHandler")
}

func cancelHandler(action: UIAlertAction) {
    //Add code of present
     print("cancelHandler")
}
```

**In NSObject Class:**

```
open class func showActionSheet(_ delegate: UIViewController, message: String, strtittle: String, actionTittle: [String], actionStyle: [UIAlertActionStyle], withHandler handler: [((UIAlertAction) -> Void)]?)
    {
        var actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController()

        if message != "" || strtittle != ""
        {
            actionSheetController = UIAlertController(title: strtittle, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
        }

        for i in 0..<actionTittle.count
        {
            actionSheetController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: actionTittle[i],
                                                          style: actionStyle[i],
                                                          handler: handler?[i]))
        }

        delegate.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Using this I can gave number of actions, their tittle and styles to action sheet. And also I can simply call this method in each class. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make extension of UIAlertController

```
extension UIAlertController{

func AlertWithTextField(_ view:UIViewController) -> UIAlertController{

    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)


        actionSheetController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No" , style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

        }))
       actionSheetController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes" , style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in

       }))


    view.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
 return actionSheetController
}
}
```

Call this from your ViewController

```
  let alert = UIAlertController()
  alert.AlertWithTextField(self)
```

Comment: I am looking for UIAlertControllerStyle.actionsheet.

Comment: You can replace alert with Actionsheet

Comment: Can I call this method in any class?

Comment: yes,Make new class of foundation    New File > Swift File > name Of File  and paste answer of extension.

Comment: Ok, Thanku. One more question how can give different number of actions, action's tittle and their style? As per requirement I have different type of action sheets in my different classes. So, each action sheet have number of  actions, action's tittle and their style. So, I want to make global function for this.

Comment: But this for specific action like if for 2. They can be change some how their can be 2 , 3, 4 or any number of actions. This is not the perfect solution. I appreciate your hard work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for review but you can change action programmatically.