# Array of closures in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift3, closures

I've a function which takes an Array parameter. This array will consists of various closures. How do I take array of closures and access that array inside the function?

```
func showAlert(_ title: String, message: String, actions: [String], handler: [()->()]) -> Void {

}

Alertift.alert(title: "test",
                           message: "test")
                .action(.default("OK")) {

                }
               .action(.default("Cancel")) {

                }
                .show(on: self)
```

Now in my function I'll be receiving the number of actions and number of associated handler or closures. Now how do I assign each action to a closure using an Array.

Comment: where is the problem? That is just a regular array like any other, access it via `handler[someIndex]` and assign that value to something-

Comment: Don't you want to add this handler to AlertController ?

Comment: @RohitaxRajguru what is the return type of `alert(title:)`?

Comment: @NiravD well it's AlertController only. Yes I'm trying to add the handlers to actions of AlertController using an Array. Alertift is just a third party library.

Comment: @RohitaxRajguru I think you want to add the closure for Ok and cancel button action, so i guess pratyush' s answer solve ur purpose

Comment: @NiravD Still it's not making use of an Array. What if in general I want to group all closures inside an Array and access them?

Comment: @RohitaxRajguru I have already answer similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/41589066/6433023 Try like this way In this answer I have just use two action but you can loop through the array and addAction one by one with AlertController

Answer (score 0):

Access closures inside your method:

```
func showAlert(_ title: String, message: String, actions: [String], handler: [()->()]) -> Void {
    for closure in handler {
        closure()
    }
}
```

Use your method with array of closures:

```
showAlert("foo", message: "bar", actions: ["foo", "bar"], handler: [{
        print("foo")
        }, {
        print("bar")
        }
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. I did not fully test this since I did not want to install the library, but you should get the idea anyway:

```
func showAlert(_ title: String, message: String, actions: [String], handler: [()->()]) -> Void {
    let alert = Alertift.alert(title: title, message: message)
    for (action, handler) in zip(actions, handler) {
        alert.action(.default(action), handler: handler)
    }
}
```

Note that it would be nicer to group the `String`s with the action directly:

```
func showAlert(_ title: String, message: String, actionsAndHandlers: [(String, ()->())]) -> Void {
    let alert = Alertift.alert(title: title, message: message)
actionsAndHandlers.forEach {
        alert.action(.default($0.0), handler: $0.1)
    }
}
```

Comment: you should `zip` and an element iterator instead: `for (action, handler) in zip(actions, handlers) { ...`

Comment: @Alexander in the first case that is not possible. In the second case I personally *sometimes* prefer foreach, iterator might be a little bit more readable though. Therefore thanks for the comment, I will leave it to OP to decide about what he feels better using.

Comment: Why isn't it possible i the first case? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Alexander ah, you edited the comment to use `zip`, then of course it is possible there as well. And in that case it is certainly better than dealing with the indices.

Answer (score 0):

In @RohitaxRajguru case, the following should work with [Alertift](https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/Alertift) v2.0 and Swift 3.

```swift
func showAlert(_ title: String, message: String, actions: [String], @escaping handler: [()->()]) -> Void {
    Alertift.alert(title: title, message: message)
        .actions(actions) { _, index, _ in
            handler[index]()
        }
        .show(on: self)
}

// ===============
showAlert("Foo", messge: "bar bazz.", actions: ["A", "B", "C"], handler: [
    {
        print("A selected")
    },
    {
        print("B selected")
    },
    {
        print("C selected")
    }
])
```

https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/Alertift

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are tying to achieve is this, have a look to the shared file -

[drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-boOF-hzYcLRDE2eWo4UFdIQnc/view)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Alert {

    var okAction : AlertSuccess?
    typealias AlertSuccess = (()->())?

    public func show(title : String?, message : String?, viewController : UIViewController?, okAction : AlertSuccess = nil) {

        let version : NSString = UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString
        if  version.doubleValue >= 8 {
            let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK".localized, style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in

                if let okAction = okAction {
                    okAction()
                }
            }))
            viewController?.present(alert, animated:true, completion:nil);
        }
    }

    public func showWithCancelAndOk(title : String, okTitle : String, cancelTitle : String, message : String, viewController : UIViewController?, okAction : AlertSuccess = nil, cancelAction : AlertSuccess = nil) {
        let version:NSString = UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString;

        if  version.doubleValue >= 8 {
            let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:.alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: cancelTitle, style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in

                if let cancelAction = cancelAction {
                    cancelAction()
                }
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: okTitle, style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in

                if let okAction = okAction {
                    okAction()
                }
            }))
            viewController?.present(alert, animated:true, completion:nil);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a link-only answer to some access-restricted site, please post the actual content on SO instead of outside of it.

Comment: Actually he has shared the code, did you try to open the link, the link contains a swift file, have a look

Comment: @Mr.Bean firstly that does not matter, it is a link-only answer, if he deletes the file the answer is worthless. Secondly it request me to "request access" to the file which I will not do.

Comment: @luk2302 the file was easily downloaded from the link, rest its his choice to upload the code as well

Comment: @Mr.Bean i repeat: that does not matter, it is a link-only answer which is on of the very few hard criteria to flag / delete an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Bean yes :) now the only problem is that the "answer" / the code does not in any way relate to OP's problem. But that is a different issue.

Comment: Still it's not making use of an Array. What if in general I want to group all closures inside an Array and access them?

Comment: @luk2302 is right it should be like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41589066/6433023